# Change HTML input value and getting the a HTML string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have `var x = "<input type='number' />"`. So that's a string. What I want is set a value to that input and in the end, get a string like this:

```
var y = "<input type='number' value='some value' />"
```

I have tried different methods but none of them worked the way I wanted.
I have tried this:

```
function myFunction(){
   $(x).val(5)
   console.log(x)
   //I get an object array
}
```

I do not want to append the element to the DOM, just want the HTML string

Comment: Before `using $(x).val()` the element needs to be attached to DOM. Try attaching it to body or some element in page abd then execute this code. It should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use `attr()` to set an attribute in the HTML, and `outerHTML` if you want the string returned, otherwise you're console logging the jQuery object, which is indeed an object.

```js
var x = "<input type='number' />";

var y = $(x).attr('value', '5');

console.log( y.get(0).outerHTML )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

To edit the value, use jQuery `prop`:

```
$(x).prop('value') = 5;
console.log(x);
```